# custom search result page

Tags: custom-post-types, search

what i did,

i create a search.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="wapper">
  <div class="contentarea clearfix">
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="search-title"> <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
        <?php _e( 'Search Results Found For', 'locale' ); ?>: "<?php the_search_query(); ?>" </h1>
      <ul>
        <?php query_posts('showposts=3'); if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <li>
          <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title();  ?>
            </a></h3>
          <?php  the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?>
          <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,200); ?>
          <div class="h-readmore"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
        </li>
        <?php endif ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

then create a searchform.php

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" id="searchform" method="get">
  <input type="search" id="searchbox" name="s" placeholder="Enter keywords" required>
    <input type="image" id="searchsubmit" alt="Search" class="searchicon" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/icon-search.gif" />
</form>
```

but my result page not showing content description and also show only one result. but on title H1 it showing 2/3/5/6/7 etc number Search Result Found. i want show at least 10 result and then page and also show 200/300 characters content text for search result. guys can help me. i am not expert wp yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have some recommendations for your question:

**First**: stop using `query_posts()`. See [the codex about this function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) to see why you shouldn't use it in themes or plugins. Anyway, if you are in a some weird situation where you have not option and you need to use `query_posts()`, you should run `wp_reset_query()` after the loop. You must know that you are using the `global $wp_query`, that contains the original query made by WordPress, and then `query_post` that alter the `global $wp_query` variable, you end up with unexpected results. Additionally, you are using a deprecated parameter `showposts`, replaced by `posts_per_page`.

**Second**: you can use a custom search template (search.php) to customize the look and feel. Just cerate a search.php file in your theme folder and customize it as you want. **Don't make custom queries here**; if you do that, you are making a new query for posts and wasting the query already done by WordPress. A waste of resources with negative performance impact.

**Third**: to change the default query parameters used by WordPress, like number of posts per page, etc, you can use [`pre_get_posts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

So, create a your search.php template as you wish and use `pre_get_posts` action to say to WordPress what parameters you want to use in the search query:

The search.php template could be something like this:

```
<?php
get_header();
global $wp_query;
?>
<div class="wapper">
  <div class="contentarea clearfix">
    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="search-title"> <?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
        <?php _e( 'Search Results Found For', 'locale' ); ?>: "<?php the_search_query(); ?>" </h1>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>

            <ul>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>

               <li>
                 <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                   <?php the_title();  ?>
                 </a></h3>
                 <?php  the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?>
                 <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,200); ?>
                 <div class="h-readmore"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
               </li>

            <?php } ?>

            </ul>

           <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the `pre_get_posts` action something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {

    // Check that it is the query we want to change: front-end search query
    if( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() ) {

        // Change the query parameters
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );

    }

} );
```

Comment: Not really necessary to use `global $wp_query` when in template context, you can just use `$wp_query` object where necessary, but I guess better be safe than sorry :-)

Comment: I was not sure about that, so I included the global reference. Thanks for the note.

Comment: @cybmeta thanks it work nice. thank you again. if you never mind then you can tell me how to add paging ?

Comment: @PieterGoosen so do you think i better replace global $wp_query; to $wp_query;

Comment: I didn't include pagination because you had not pagination in your code, I just copy your code without the custom query part. You could use any of the [functions provided by WordPress for multiple posts pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).

Comment: No, you can leave it as is :-).

Answer (score 1):

You have to run the loop  , modify your search.php something similar to the code below

```
  <?php get_header();?>

    <div class="wapper">
      <div class="contentarea clearfix">
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <p><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_search_query() ); ?></p>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

                        <?php
                        // Start the Loop.
                        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        ?>
                        <li><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></li>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium') ?>
                        <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 200); ?>
                            <div class="h-readmore"> 
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        endwhile;
                else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                endif;
                ?>       
            </ul>                                 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: In the above code change 'twentyfourteen' to your theme text domain

Comment: thanks. if giving me error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in .../search.php on line 34